# Debounce ShinyFilters

Tags: r, shiny

ShinyFilters is a useful package but when there is a long list in one of the filters that are being selected one by one the reactive variable refreshes with each selection and this is problematic. I am unsuccessful in my efforts to debounce ShinyFilters. The example from the shinyFilters reference page https://github.com/davesteps/shinyFilters is below and one of my unsuccessful attempts is included but commented out. I've used https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/debounce.html and [How to use debounce with reactiveValues in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296342/how-to-use-debounce-with-reactivevalues-in-shiny) as references. Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyFilters)


# create filterset in global section of app
filterSet <- newFilterSet('FS1') %>%
  # give each filter unique id and tell it which column to filter on
  addSelectFilter('cylinders','cyl') %>%
  addSelectFilter('gears','gear') %>%
  addSliderFilter('disp',value=c(0,500)) %>%
  addSelectFilter('carb') %>%
  addCustomSliderFilter('hp',value=seq(0,500,50))


ui <- fluidPage(
  #shinyjs is required to show/hide filters
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      filterInputs(filterSet),
      hr(),
      filterMaster(filterSet),
      filterResetButton(filterSet)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # wrap data in reactive expression in case you
  # need to do something to the data before filtering
  data <- reactive(mtcars)

  # initialize the filter set
  filterSet <- initializeFilterSet(filterSet, data) 
  # filterSet <- filterSet %>% debounce(1000)

  # the output is a reactive data.frame
  output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(filterSet$output())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```